# How to move a button under input?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a quite weird problem, which I can't find solution on

So basically what I want is to make is to bring button under the input file (I'm using Bootstrap), but have no idea how to do that

```html
<form>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Numer pokoju" name="numerPokoju" required="">
 <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="46d2ce8a-2271-471f-a46f-c58234324e99">
 <button type="button">
  Sprawdź
 </button>
</form>
```

here's the visualization [on CodePen](https://codepen.io/Zeczero/pen/MWwJdvj)

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question here on Stack Overflow, not only on an external site. I've taken the liberty of adding a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to your question, but you need to add CSS of what you've tried.

Comment: use a [`br` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) - that's what they're for

Answer (score 3):

Simply, wrap the `button` and `input` inside `form-group` div and voila!

```
  <div class="form-group">
            <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="46d2ce8a-2271-471f-a46f-c58234324e99">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button">
                Sprawdź
            </button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Button is an inline element. So what you can do is make it a block element.

Way 1: As you mentioned you are using Bootstrap. So add class `d-block` to button.

Way 2: In general add this to css file :

```
button {
 display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap as help classes for that:

```
            <form class="d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
```

```css
.card {
  background: rgba(18, 13, 33, .8)!important;
  color: #d7eaf4;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px #000000c0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body text-center">
    <h5 class="card-title mb-2">
      text string
    </h5>
    <div class="subtitle mb-3">
      by me
    </div>
    <form class="d-flex flex-column align-items-start">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Numer pokoju" name="numerPokoju" required="">
      <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="46d2ce8a-2271-471f-a46f-c58234324e99">
      <button type="button">
      Sprawdź
     </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to approach this, you can simply change input display to block eg:

```
input[type=text] {
    display:block;
}
```

or more complex way is use flex for example:

```
.form-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

or just move the input field into `<div>` element.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Bootstrap classes from [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/forms/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button and the input fields are currently set to display:inline. If you want them to use the whole line you can use display: block

Bootstrap has a class called d-block which can be added to your element to change the display type to block.

```
<button type="button" class="d-block">
    Sprawdź
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can:

## 1

```
button {
    display: block;
}
```

## 2

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Numer pokoju" name="numerPokoju" required="">
    <input name="csrf" type="hidden" value="46d2ce8a-2271-471f-a46f-c58234324e99">
    <br>
    <button type="button">
        Sprawdź
    </button>
</form>
```

## 3

```
input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

## 4

etc.